# How to sort YouTube video by number of viewers in URL?

Tags: youtube

I want to sort Live YouTube channel by the number of viewers.

How to do that from the URL?

Or any others options?

`https://www.youtube.com/channel/SBAaOjE-GIlRI/videos?view=19&sort=p`

`&sort=p`
Most popular.

Answer (score 3):

Please, try this - **sort=video_view_count**:

https://www.youtube.com/channel/SBAaOjE-GIlRI/videos?view=19&sort=video_view_count